# How to write two lists to two columns of one row to a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write lists to a CSV. each list as a string with brackets to each column in a one row.
Here's what I've tried till now:

```
from csv import writer
new_csv_file = "new sheet.csv"
a_list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "ab", 8, 9]
a_list_2 = ["cd", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "ab", 8, 9]
with open(new_csv_file, 'a', newline="") as fd:
    csv_writer = writer(fd, delimiter=',')
    for i in [a_list, a_list_2]:
        csv_writer.writerow([i])
    fd.write("\n")
```

This is what above code gives me:
[image]

This is how I want it, with a new line at end for appending more lists in next row in next loop the same way:
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the for loop:

```
from csv import writer
new_csv_file = "new sheet.csv"
a_list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "ab", 8, 9]
a_list_2 = ["cd", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "ab", 8, 9]
with open(new_csv_file, 'a', newline="") as fd:
    csv_writer = writer(fd, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerow([a_list, a_list_2])
    fd.write("\n")
```